# How 10 IS HEX 5 bytes?

Tags: malware

I am stuck in this video. Please solve this issue.

This video is about Encryption and Decryption using  Win32 API.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQuRwpUTBpQ

In this video **27:07** it's saying "10 IS HEX 5 bytes?" But how?

Please watch  this video to understand?

Comment: This means 10 is the length of ASCII string in which every char relates a nibble (half byte in hex).

Comment: The wording is awkward. He's say that given a hexadecimal string, 10 characters in that string represent 5 bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The length of 10 is simply the number of characters selected.
Each hexadecimal digit requires 4 bits (`0`..`F`).
So 10 hexadecimal digits take 40 bits (4 bits x 10) or 5 bytes (8 bits x 5).